# How to make Primefaces growl message visible when I switch between pages?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with Primefaces growl. I want to make visible message when I switch between pages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In the @PostConstruct method (or the constructor) of the second page's bean, add a FacesMessage, e.g.:

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Growl Message", "Growl Message Text"));
```

Comment: Note that the bean must be `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: I forgot to mention about one detail: I have a JSF page `Accounts` where I can see a list of a users and I also have JSF page with form for adding users. I want when I add new user to redirect the user to page `Accounts` and display Primefaces growl message "Success". In this example every time when I refresh page `Accounts` I will see the message. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: try adding redisplay="false" to your growl component definition e.g. <p:growl ... redisplay="false"/>

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please remember to mark it as approved using the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It will show the msg in the current page before redirect.

HTML:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:growl />
    <p:button outcome="gotoABC" id="rdr-btn" style="display: none;" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.process()}" update="@form" />
</form>
```

Bean:

```
public void process(){
    addInfoMsg(summary, msgDetail); //Add msg func
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("setTimeout(function(){ $('#rdr-btn').click(); }, 3000);"); // 3 seconds delay. I put the script in Constants to config later.
}
```